# How do I get table to be 100% height in HTML email

Tags: html, css, email

I'm building an HTML emailer and am having trouble with my right column to fill 100% of the height.

If you check out my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zQNS4/143/

You'll see I want the right column (grey bar) to fill all the way down to be equal in height with the left side. How would I do that?

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body >
<div align="center">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600">

    <!--Logo-->
    <tr>
      <td width="600" colspan="2" align="left" valign="top">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="600" style="padding: 0px 0px 8px 0px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#616161" align="right" valign="bottom"><div class="mktEditable" id="header-text">Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</div></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>

    <!--Box, two columns: 400,200-->
    <tr>
      <td width="600" colspan="2" align="left" valign="top" style="border:1px solid #d1d1d1">
      <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="400" valign="top" align="left" style="padding: 22px 12px 10px 30px; color:#616161; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:16px">


              <br>
              <div class="mktEditable" id="header-body">
                <div style="color:#f66511; font-size:23px; line-height:27px; margin-bottom:5px"> Pharetra Euismod Venenatis Tortor Consectetur </div>
              </div>
              <div class="mktEditable" id="subhead-body"> <span style="font-size:14px; line-height:18px; margin:0; display:block"> Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient </span><br>
              </div>
              <div class="mktEditable" id="body">

<p style="font-size:12px;color:#616161;line-height:17px; margin:10px 0 10px 0;text-align:left">
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient.</p>


              </div></td>
            <td width="200" align="right" valign="top"  style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="190" bgcolor="#e2e3e4" style="border:1px solid #bdbcbc">
                <tr>
                  <td width="190"  align="right" valign="top" >
                  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#e2e3e4">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="190" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 92px 25px 0 25px;"><div class="mktEditable" id="sidebar-body">
                        <p style="font-size:16px;color:#616161;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left">
                            <strong>Questions?</strong></p>
                        <p style="font-size:12px;line-height:17px;color:#616161;font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left">
                            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient </p>
</div></td>
                      </tr>
                  </table></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you set height="100%"? try on both table and also td itself. Else I would just use 1 table for your approach.

Comment: you definitely need to make that into one table.  The left column goes in the first td, and the right column goes in the second td.  Then the heights will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways. The easiest, but less versatile is to put a pixel height on your grey table `<td height="400">`. This will force it to be that high. Of course this doesn't make it flow to different heights driven by the main section.

To have it 100% of the content in the main section and adjust automatically to the height, you'll have to remove the nested table. Try laying it out like this instead:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
  <tr>
    <td width="30" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="340" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="180" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="400">
          Main content here...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
    </td>
    <td width="30">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="120" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      Panel Here<br>...<br>...<br>...
    </td>
    <td width="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="340" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="30" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="180" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="20" height="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```